# Sarrus's rule and Cofactors

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm hoping that somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong. I have the following matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \cos x & -r\sin x & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \sin x & r\cos x & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}. $$

When I calculate the determinant using Sarrus's rule I get 
$$ 0+(-r\sin^2x)+0-0-r\cos^2x-0 = -r. $$

If I use cofactors I get $r$.

What gives?

Cheers
Andy

Comment: Don't forget about the checkerboard. :) You can also use "\sin" and "\cos" which give you $\sin$ and $\cos$ respectively.

Comment: Cheers. Totally forgot the checkerboard. And my mathjax

Answer (score 1):

When you use cofactors, it's 
$$
(-1)\,(r\cos^2x+r\sin^2x)=-r.
$$
The $2,3$ entry is "odd", so it carries a negative sign.